# cannot get request header

Tags: go, go-echo

I tried to print the request header using the echo framework, but it seems the echo framework does not load the header into the context.request.Header fields. Is this a bug for the echo framework?

Here is the main function, and context.Request() is a type of *http.Request,

```
func main() {
    server := echo.New()

    server.GET("/", func(context echo.Context) error {

        for key, values := range context.Request().Header {
            fmt.Println(key)
            for value := range values {
                fmt.Println(value)
            }
        }
        return nil
    })

    server.Logger.Fatal(server.Start(":12312"))
}
```

I use curl `curl -vvv "http://127.0.0.1:12312/"` to test the server, but the server only print

```
User-Agent
0
Accept
0
```

but actually, the curl gives the following as header info

```
> Host: 127.0.0.1:12312
> User-Agent: curl/7.64.1
> Accept: */*
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        for value := range values {
```

Using `range` on a list returns `index, value`. You only ask for the `index`, which is `0` in all cases. To get the actual values use

```
        for _,value := range values {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't edit @Steffen to show the complete code I'll add it here:

```
func main() {
    server := echo.New()

    server.GET("/", func(context echo.Context) error {

        for key, values := range context.Request().Header {
            fmt.Println(key)
            for _,value := range values {
                fmt.Println(value)
            }
        }
        return nil
    })

    server.Logger.Fatal(server.Start(":12312"))
}
```